# trying get total from grid view textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i want to get value from grid view text box in Text Change Event but error comes
Object refrence is not set of an instance of an Object

```
Protected Sub onDebitChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim a, b As Integer

    With GridView3
        Dim rows As Integer = .Rows.Count
        For i As Integer = 0 To rows - 1
            Dim txtDebit As TextBox = CType(GridView3.Rows(i).FindControl("TotalDebit"), TextBox)

            a = Val(txtDebit.Text)

            b += a
        Next

        DebitBalance.Text = b
    End With
End Sub
```

i also had tried for each loop but error is same
please help

Comment: On which line you are getting this error? I guess its on txtDebit.Text correct if i am wrong.

Comment: please post the markup for the GridView.

Comment: specifically what is not set to an object ref, would be a good start.

Comment: kundan a = Val(txtDebit.Text) this line have error

Comment: Black baron.   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Debit">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Debit" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged ="onDebitChange" runat="server" Width="40px" Text="0" 
                                onkeydown = "return allowOnlyNumber(event);">
                                </asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: as a start, the only textbox in the GridView has the ID: "Debit" not "TotalDebit", so if you're trying to access it you must put the correct ID. try fixing it and if it didn't work then you have to update the question with the full markup code in order to get the solution faster.

Comment: Oh Black Baron Very Very Thank full and sorry it's my Mistake. yes you are right that control name is "Debit" not "TotalDebit". Now i have solve my problem. and next time i'll be care full about code and post the codes always in the question not in comments. 
but where i mark a good answer for you ? :)

Comment: glad it worked for you :) I posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the name of the ItemTemplate control correctly, in `onDebitChange` method please fix the control name to "Debit" not "TotalDebit" only:

```
Dim txtDebit As TextBox = CType(GridView3.Rows(i).FindControl("Debit"), TextBox)
```

Hope this helps.